# Enviar Imagem junto com texto para o Discord Usando Webhooks

Tags: php, webhook

Estou tentando fazer um script que mande noticias, atualizações, para um servidor do *Discord*, para isso necessito de usar o sistema de *Webhooks*. Eu já montei todo o sistema, inclusive já esta tudo funcionando.

Mas o sistema que fiz só envia texto, e eu gostaria de fazer esse sistema para enviar também junto com o texto, duas imagens, para ficar um layout bem legal para as notícias.

No *PHP* estou usando o seguinte código para mandar as mensagens para o discord:

```
<?php
function postToDiscord($message) {
    $data = array("content" => $message, "username" => "News");
    $curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/2225546.......");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}
?>
```

Só que o dessa maneira só envia texto. Ficando assim lá no discord:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu queria que a notícia aparecesse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conseguem me intender? 
Quero enviar essas imagens do topo e do rodapé junto com o texto, para que as notícias aparecem com um visual mais bonito.

---

Para vocês entenderem melhor como funciona o sistema Adicionem o Servidor de Teste que crie no discord e o site que envia as noticias para o discord:

discord: https://discord.gg/6nGdjnz
Site de postagem: http://diegodevphp.esy.es/

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários jeitos de se fazer o que deseja utilizando *CURL*, uma dela é:

```
$data = array("content" => $message, "username" => "News", "file" => "ENDERECO_DA_IMAGEM/IMAGEM.jpeg");
// Se sua versão do PHP for igual ou acima de 5.6.0
// a linha abaixo é necessária
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```